# Could you please help me figure out how to organize the data in my quiz program?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a multiple-choice quiz using JavaFX. Each question would hold the question, the possible answers and the correct answer. Below I have some working code, but it's all in one class. I realize I should have the data in another class (or classes) and that I shouldn't use parallel arrays. That other class should also contain methods for setting the text on the question label and the answer buttons and changing them when the user presses "next". I also need a method to let the user know if their answer was correct or not. 
The problem is that I have no idea how to organize the data and how to make the methods in the other class interact with the GUI. Could you please give me some ideas on how to approach this assignment?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Quiz extends Application {

private int questionNumber = 0 ;

private int max = 5;

String[] question = new String[max];

String [] answer1 = new String[max];

String [] answer2 = new String [max];

String [] answer3 = new String[max];

Label label = new Label();

Label userAnswer = new Label();

RadioButton choice1 = new RadioButton();

RadioButton choice2 = new RadioButton();

RadioButton choice3 = new RadioButton();

ToggleGroup answers = new ToggleGroup();

Button next = new Button("Next");

RadioButton userAnswered;

TilePane buttons = new TilePane();

Button answer = new Button("Answer");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}

@Override

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    question[0]= "What's the capital  of Monaco?";
    question[1] = "What's the capital of San Marino?";
    question[2] = "What's the capital of Lithuania?";
    question[3] = "What's the capital of Denmark?";
    question[4] = "What's the capital of Finland?";


    label.setFont(new Font("Cambria", 26));
    label.setTranslateY(230);
    label.setTranslateX(230);
    label.setText(question[0]);

    HBox answerArea = new HBox();
    answerArea.setTranslateY(330);
    answerArea.setTranslateX(260);
    answerArea.setSpacing(20);


    answer1 [0] =  "Monte Carlo";
    answer1 [1] =  "San Marino";  
    answer1 [2] =  "Kaunas";
    answer1 [3] =  "Copenhagen";  
    answer1 [4] = "Tampere";


    answer2[0] = "Monaco";  
    answer2[1] = "Kairo";
    answer2[2] = "Warsav";
    answer2[3] = "Oslo";
    answer2 [4] = "Helsinki";  

    answer3 [0]= "Tirana";
    answer3 [1]= "Zagreb";
    answer3 [2]= "Vilnius";   
    answer3 [3]= "Stockholm";
    answer3 [4]= "Turku";



    choice1.setText(answer1[0]);
    choice2.setText(answer2[0]);
    choice3.setText(answer3[0]);

    choice1.setToggleGroup(answers);
    choice2.setToggleGroup(answers);
    choice3.setToggleGroup(answers);

    answer.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    answer.setOnAction(e -> questionAnswered());

    answers.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {

           userAnswered = (RadioButton) newValue.getToggleGroup().getSelectedToggle(); // Cast objekt  to radiobutton

        }
    });
   userAnswer.setTranslateY(280);
   userAnswer.setTranslateX(360);
   userAnswer.setFont(new Font("Cambria", 16));

    answerArea.getChildren().addAll(choice1, choice2, choice3);



    next.setOnAction(e -> nextQuestion());
    next.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);


    buttons.setTranslateY(400);
    buttons.setTranslateX(280);
    buttons.setHgap(5);

    buttons.getChildren().addA(next);

    answer.setTranslateX(550);
    answer.setTranslateY(330);


    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();

    pane.getChildren().addAll(label, answerArea, buttons, answer, userAnswer);

}


public void questionAnswered(){

    if (userAnswered.equals(choice2)) {
        userAnswer.setText("Correct");
    } else {
        userAnswer.setText("Wrong answer");
    }

}

public void nextQuestion() {
    questionNumber = (questionNumber + 1) % question.length ;
    label.setText(question[questionNumber]);
    choice1.setText(answer1[questionNumber]);
    choice2.setText(answer2[questionNumber]);
    choice3.setText(answer3[questionNumber]);


    userAnswer.setText(" ");

    });

}
  }
```

Comment: This is the reason, why for loops are invented :D

Comment: Here the need of OOP approach arises. If you noticed, based on your own explanation, the first class you should start to create is `QuizQuestion`, which has `question`, 4 `answer`s and `correctAnswerNum` fields and constructor for it. Then you can use it as `QuizQuestion qq = new QuizQuestion("Question?", "Answer-1", "Answer-2", "Answer-3", "Answer-4", 3);` where the 3 means the correct answer is 3rd one.

Comment: Thank you for advice! Do I understand correct that in this case I would create the actual QuizQuestion objects in the third class and the methods for getting the next question in GUI and evaluating the user's answer should also be in this third class?

Comment: Yes you can create a QuizController (QuizManager) class as @mixmastered stated in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of task provides a classic example of OOP and MVC principles. As @UlukBiy points out - you even mention potential object classes in your explanation (eq `Question`/`Answer`). Such classes would make up your model.

Most of what you have so far is centered around the user interface (view).

The third component would be the controller (named something like `QuizController`). This would manage the question bank (something like `List<Question> questions`), and be where methods such as `nextQuestion()` would be located.

It's probably worth bearing in mind that as the number of questions/answers increases, you would look to use some external data source (database/xml file) - but it seems hard coding the questions would be sufficient for you here (some `populateQuestionBank()` method in the controller perhaps?)

For more info on the MVC pattern:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, I hope I can make these methods work. And yes, I'm going to have more questions and eventually I will have to read the data from a file, I just thought I'd try to make it look like a normal program first.